# how to wait jquery ajax call when page load

Tags: jquery

I have got a question with jquery ajax. In my index page, I have the jquery ajax callback function that read xml and create dynamic html tag with data from xml. Its all working fine but jquery sliderkit plugin not working as the page is not fully loaded with html tag.

How could I force to wait the page fully loaded and then call plugin?

I have tried adding the plugin at the bottom of page but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the sliderkit inside of the ajax success call then, since from what I understand from your question it depends on the result of the AJAX html injection.